# IONIC | How can i access ionic html tags inside my JS file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I want to change the value of **ion-nav-button (side)**, **button(menu-toggle)** and **ion-side-menu(side)** from **LEFT** to **RIGHT**. how can i do this?

Here is my Code:

```
 <ion-nav-buttons id="navButton" side="left">
    <button id="toggleButton" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

and

```
<ion-side-menu id="sideMenuId" side="left">
```

I want to change the values of above mentioned  from left to right on button click.

Answer (score 0):

$ionicNavBarDelegate delegate for controlling the ionNavBar directive and supports different methods. It is injected into the controller to access its properties and methods.
link : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/

Another way to access html is 
create custom attribute directive and within the directive we can access corresponding element and manipulate DOM.

Comment: this is not the answer of my question.